# How to integrate my flutter package into a website that is not written in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, integration

I am currently developing a flutter Chat application that I would like to add to an existing website developed in React. But I'm not sure how to do that or even if it's possible.

I found articles about adding flutter to android or iOS apps. But I found nothing that could help me with integrating a flutter package into a website.

Comment: hi @pariya-negahdari-pour , welcome to https://stackoverflow.com , you can  google it :`Element Embedding in Flutter Web`  or see this article https://medium.com/simform-engineering/element-embedding-in-flutter-web-ef764fc64410

Comment: Thank you very much. I still need to consider how to implement a proper interface due to challenges concerning authentication. If you have any insights in that regard, i'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: you're welcome. Just to follow the `stackoverflow guidelines` ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ), please ask the question with `debug details` and `reproduce code` . And do it as a `new question` or `update` the current question.